# How to deal with a weak manager?

Tags: management, government, hierarchy, healthcare-industry

I work in the healthcare sector.

I am managing a team and IT professionals.

above me, there is a director whose main experience is in accounting and who does not have strong experience in the field, although he knows the business side of the work.

Anyway, when I say weak I do not mean weak in experience, I mean weak in management.

When he hears from someone he just acts upon what he hears and we ended with some very wrong situations that affect the efficiency and harmony of my team.

I wonder what is the right approach to handling this kind of situation.

P.S. If I try to tell him this is wrong his ego does not accept that as he thinks he knows everything.

Example: He wanted to sack one of my team members because one consultant (who was the ex-team lead) told him he was not good.

Example: He wants to have 2 managers for my team! because the (ex-team leader) wanted to be a manager.

Comment: I'm sorry, but without an actual example, we can't help you. Your current example is so vague, that even a 1000 pages answer probably wouldn't answer your question.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk example provided

Comment: Have you talked to _his_ manager about this?

Comment: Yes talking to his manager, or even managers of his level, seems like an appropriate course of action; he may not be willing to hear your ideas from you, but perhaps they will listen to a person of the same seniority/higher seniority (as childish as that may be)

Comment: @keshlam by his manager, do you mean my manager's manager?

Comment: @asmgx: yes. Your second-line manager is responsible  for training/guiding your own manager's performance. If there is is a genuine problem that your manager can not correct independently, the second line should know about it so he can take appropriate steps. Obviously there is some risk involved if it appears that you are the one who is being unreasonable, but if you want this fixed that's your next step. Either that, or get out from under that manager, which is also something to take up with the second-line. Or start interviewing elsewhere. Pick one or several.

Answer (score 0):

If your manager is weak, then assert yourself.

Pre-empt the issues with your agenda and override your manager. People like this tend to take whatever comes first as the easiest road and then stick to it as it's often more drama to change their minds then keep on.